# Detect the event on page load jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following which is working fine, just need a bit of change that if i refresh a page and the dropdown already has a selcted of yes, just execute the code, right now, i am just doing the code on the change request.

```
$('#internalNoteopen').bind('change load',function() {
        var str = $('#internalNoteopen').val();
        if (str == 'Yes') {
            $('#note').show('slow');    
        }
        else {
            $('#note').hide('slow');        
        }
    });
```

I have myself added the load event to see if that works, but that is not working, maybe some kind of on event could work, but not sure how it will work.

Guide me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the change event on page load:

```
$('#internalNoteopen').bind('change load',function() {
    var str = $('#internalNoteopen').val();
    if (str == 'Yes') {
        $('#note').show('slow');    
    }
    else {
        $('#note').hide('slow');        
    }
}).trigger('change'); // or .change()
```

Comment: @user3454903 the change event requires an actual browser event initiated by the user. So the trick here is to trigger it automatically. Also, it's recommended to use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` for events manipulation.

Comment: ok, Thanks, Does the same type of case applies to `propertychange`, suppose the Event `propertychange` is applicable in IE only, what alternatives we have for other browsers, does this trick works there too.